# Generate and set self links in nested items

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jersey, jax-rs

I should migrate some code from jax-rs to spring mvc. We had a controller, which response with an object and set at the same time links in a list :

```
HateoasResponse.ok(content)
               .selfLink(FieldPath.path("categories"), "some_controller_id", "id")
               .build()
```

Did any one know, if there is something similar in spring mvc ?
I have checked spring-hateoas. If I use it , I should modify my models to something supported by this package (`CollectionModel`, `EnitityModel`..)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the response object extend `ResourceSupport` and then generate the links as follows.

```
org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(YourSpringMvcController.class)
    .methodWhichHasMappingTo(param1,param2,paramN))
    .withRel("relationOfThisLinkToTheRequestedResource").expand();
```

This link can then be added to the response object using the resource add method.

for example, let's say you have a controller like the following:

```
@RestController
public class OrderController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/orders/{orderId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Order> getOrder(@Valid @PathVariable Integer orderId) {
        return getOrder(orderId);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/orders/{orderId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Order> deleteOrder(@Valid @PathVariable Integer orderId) {
        return orderRepo.deleteOrder(orderId);
    }
}
```

then for a request to GET orders, you would build the response like the following:
`Order` which is a response entity will extend `ResourceSupport`

```
public Order getOrder(int orderId){
    Order order = repo.findByOrderId(orderId);
    Link deleteLink = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(OrderController.class)
                        .deleteOrder(orderId))
                        .withRel("delete").expand();
    
    order.add(deleteLink);

    Link selfLink = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(OrderController.class)
                        .getOrder(orderId))
                        .withSelfRel();
    
    order.add(selfLink);
    return order;
}
```

Hope this helps.